# Norm of a Functional Restricted to a Subspace

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space, $Y \subset X$ a closed subspace. Let $x^* \in X^*$ be such that $\|x^*\| = \sup_{x \in B_X} |x^*(x)| = 1$. Is it then true that $\|x^*|_Y\| = \sup_{y \in B_Y} |x^*(y)| = 1$ too? ($x^*|_Y$ is the restriction of $x^*$ to $Y$)

If we take $y \in B_Y$ then from $\|x^*\| = 1$ it follows $\|x^*|_Y\| \leq 1$. I do not see how to prove it is equal to one.

Comment: It is trivially false. Take $Y=$ a line $\subset X=$ a plane, and find $x^*$ of norm $1$ s.t. $x^*|_Y=0.$

Answer (score 1):

At the extreme, you can have $Y=\ker x^*$, and so $\|x^*|_Y\|=0$.

And anything in between is possible. Let $X=\mathbb C^2$, put $x^*(a,b)=a$. Then $\|x^*\|=1$. For any $t\in[0,1]$, if you take $Y=\mathbb C\,(t,\sqrt{1-t^2})$, then
$$
\|x^*|_Y\|=t.
$$